# I want to store the data of multiple cases into a table

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I want to store the data of multiple cases into a table for that I am using visualforce to create a table and then I am rendering it as a pdf. I am also SOQL query in apex class to fetch the data from multiple cases and then I am passing the id of the case in PageReference.getParameters.put() method below is the code

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/AssetManagementReport');

System.debug('Id = '+parentId);

```
List<Case> cs = [SELECT Id, Unit_Number__c, Current_effective_date__c, Occupants__c, Unit_Type__c, Move_In_Date__c,
 Tenant_Income_Certification_Date__c, Asset__c, Income_Set_Aside__c, Rent_Set_Aside__c, Certified_Income_audit__c
, Verified_Income__c, Tenant_paid_rent__c from Case where Audit_Request_Name__c =: parentId ];



        for(Case cid: cs)
        {
              pageRef.getParameters().put( 'id',cid.Id);
        }
```

But it is overriding the case id and taking only last case id and inside the table, I am getting only one record

So please tell me how to pass multiple case id and  store the records of multiple cases in table

Answer (score 0):

```
pageRef.getParameters().put( 'id',cid.Id);
```

This is how maps work. If you use the same value more than once, it overwrites the previous value.

Instead, you need to serialize the list:

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('caseIds',String.join(cid,','));
```

In your other page, you'll need to split them apart again.

```
String[] caseIds = ApexPages.currentPgae().getParameters().get('caseIds').split(',');
```

Comment: I am using VIsualforce page as another page so how to add below code in vf page   String[] caseIds = ApexPages.currentPgae().getParameters().get('caseIds').split(',');

Comment: how to split the id into vf page ?

Comment: @HarshitVermabluCursor The code you had in your comment should work? What problems are you encountering?